# PHP shorthand if/else ternary

Tags: php

How can I make this a one or two line shorthand ternary?

```
if ($tame == null): 
    echo $tame = '0' . '<br />';
else: 
    echo $tame . '<br />';
endif;
```

Comment: Did you mean to assign `0<br />` to `$tame` in the first `echo` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the OP is expecting $tame to be an integer value. Why else would he write zero for null?

If this is the case. This is the shortest solution.

```
echo (int)$tame.'<br/>';
```

That will echo 0 for null or a numeric value. There is also no reason to set $tame to zero, because PHP treats null and zero the same.

Comment: He didn't really imply that, so we don't really know.

Comment: True, but I'm trying to be smart ;)

Comment: If he is intending for `$tame` to be an integer this would be the best answer, but for the complete solution you still need to set it equal to zero so I would do this - `echo ($tame = (int)$tame), '<br />';`

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst nice touch!

Comment: Nice, beat mine by 8 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
$tame = ($tame == null) ? 0 : $tame;
echo $tame . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $tame == null ? $tame = '0<br />' : $tame.'<br />';
```

Comment: He wants to also set `$tame` equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ($tame == null ? ($tame = 0) : $tame), '<br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is essentially an `if..else` statement in one line.

```
if (condition) {
    action(a);
} else {
    action(b);
}
```

turns into:

```
action( condition ? a : b );
```

What you have is:

```
if ($tame == null) {
    echo $tame = '0' . '<br />';
} else {
    echo $tame . '<br />';
}
```

which could be written as:

```
echo $tame == null ? $tame = '0<br />' : $tame . '<br />';
```

However, this ternary statement is relatively complex, given that `$tame` is being mutated as part of the statement. Code written this way is harder to read, and therefor difficult to debug, which makes it more prone to errors. It would be better overall if you wrote the code in the more verbose form:

```
if ($tame == null) {
    $tame = '0';
}
echo $tame . '<br />';
```

Comment: "Which could be written as.." - That would include the linebreak in `$tame` which I don't think he was going for.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, that's what he'd be getting whether or not he intended it. As I said: harder to read = difficult to debug = prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (is_null($tame)) ? '0<br />' : $tame . '<br />';
```

Comment: This is not the same as what was written. `$tame` was mutated in the original.

Comment: That assignment seems like a mistake. Otherwise the known value of `$tame` would likely already have a `<br />` at the end, then printing an extra br tag.

Answer (score 0):

How about one more way :)

```
echo $tame . (!is_null($tame)?:'0'). '<br />';
```

as you can see I omitted the middle part, since php 5.3 you can do it like this

The ternary part is only the part which is needed to be printed you can still do it like this for older php

```
echo $tame . (is_null($tame)?'0':''). '<br />';
```

Comment: He wants to also set `$tame` equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If `$tame` is null or an integer, you can skip the logic altogether:

```
echo sprintf("%d<br />", $tame);
```

This assumes you didn't mean to assign `"0<br />"` to `$tame` in the second line, as pointed out by @mellamokb.