# echo php javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I echo this javascript if the php error messages is called? I have an error message setting that when a user misses his username or password it triggers an error message. The php error message is called by a php code. Here is the code:

```
<?php echo showmessage($msg) ?>
```

I have an alert message in javascript that when called it will make a javascript css pop up alert box. IF the javascript code is present it will show the alert box right away after reload. Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function () {  
   jqxAlert.alert('Alert Message');  
  })  
</script>
```

How can I incorporate so that when the php echo message comes up it will trigger the javscript alert message. I was trying an if in php, so something like this code:

```
if ( showmessage($msg) ) {
   <script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function () {  
         jqxAlert.alert('Alert Message');  
     })  
   </script>
}
```

How can I echo my javascript message on the php call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This could be written like this:

[endif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

[endif-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564130/difference-between-if-and-if-endif)

```
<?php if (showmessage($msg)): ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            jqxAlert.alert('Alert Message');
        });
    </script> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

*Or like this:*

```
<?php if (showmessage($msg)) { ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            jqxAlert.alert('Alert Message');
        });
    </script> 
<?php } ?>
```

*Or like this:*

```
<?php 

    if (showmessage($msg)) { 
        echo
        '
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function (){
                    jqxAlert.alert(\'Alert Message\');
                });
            </script> 
        ';
    } 

?>
```

[short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

[short hand comparison (ternary)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

[ternary 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410485/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary)

*Or even this (probably not the best idea though):*

```
<?= (showmessage($msg)) ? '<script>$(document).ready(function (){jqxAlert.alert(\'Alert Message\');});</script>' : ""; ?>
```

### Alternatively, if you mean you would like to put the error message *in* that alertbox

```
<?php 

    if (showmessage($msg)) { 
        echo
        '
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function (){
                    jqxAlert.alert('.showmessage($msg).');
                });
            </script> 
        ';
    } 

?>
```

*and again in the first style:*

```
<?php if (showmessage($msg)): ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            jqxAlert.alert(<?= showmessage($msg) ?>);
        });
    </script> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this.. close your php tag before starting to write javascript..

```
<?php if ( showmessage($msg) ) { ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">  
       alert('Alert Message');
   </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
     <?PHP if ( showmessage($msg) ) {  ?>
         <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {
                   jqxAlert.alert('Alert Message');
                });
           </script> 
     <?PHP } ?>
```

Comment: @AnaesArias not exactly, he/she closed the php tag

Comment: you missed to add the PHP tags, check the PHP condition STARTING and END section

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function, I think this is the most practice way to do it:

**1.define a function:**

```
<?php function phpAlert($msg) {  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' .$msg. '")</script>';}  ?>
```

**2. call it like this:**

```
<?php phpAlert(   "Hello world!\\n\\nPHP has got an Alert Box"   );  ?>
```